# Azure Active Directory Client Secrets in SPA Applications

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure Active Directory to secure my ASP.NET Core API's and SPA applications. Currently, I'm not using a client secret, which is fine for SPA applications because it would would visible in the public JavaScript.

If I were to add a client secret to one of my API's, how do I tell Azure Active Directory that I don't want to use the client secret for my SPA but do want to use it in my other API's when I am making API to API calls?

Comment: you use user credential to secure your API at the moment from SPA?

Comment: @CuongLe Yes, Azure AD redirects to a login page, user enters their login info and redirects back to the SPA app.

Comment: Why don't you use username/password directly to get token instead of using client secret?

Answer (score 2):

Your API needs to be a separate application in Azure AD in that case. If they are the same application, the client secret will work from anywhere.

Though actually since it is a SPA, the only way it could use the secret would be through AJAX, and Azure AD does not support CORS and blocks that.

And even if it were to work in the future, it should go without saying that you should never put your client secret in client-side code. This includes front-side JavaScript in web applications and code in mobile applications. (I know this was clear to you, but making sure someone else reading the answer later also understands this.) Someone could with relative ease grab the secret from there, and then if your app had permissions on some APIs.. You get where this is going.

Comment: The point of not using secrets with SPAs is that they end up in the browser, visible for everyone (including attackers) that load the SPA; that's independent of AJAX or how it is used.

Comment: Yes, obviously. That was clear for OP as well. I was simply stating that you actually couldn't do that even if you wanted to. I'll add that to the answer anyway :)